# How is PlayStation (4/5) protected from disk-copying piracy?

Tags: disk-encryption, disk-image

It just doesn't make any sense to me. Any owner of a original PS game disk has full access to it, so it shouldn't be a problem to create an identical disk, isn't it? And PS won't be able to tell apart identical disks, will it?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-PS4-recognize-between-a-burned-or-an-original-game-Blu-ray